# Can I, with a single cut command, create two output files for the two fields of my input file?

Tags: cut

I could write a shell script to do it in a loop, but is there a one line solution using the terminal ?

Comment: Maybe with something else, but not with `cut`. `cut` just writes to stdout. There is only one stdout. Therefore you can't create 2 files.

Comment: There might be a way of doing this by combining `cut` and `tee` or maybe other tools but for that we would need some sample input data and required output. please be more explicit in your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with one `cut` command. You could do it with `awk`:

```
awk -F '\t' '{print $1 > "file1"; print $2 > "file2"}' < file
```

Or for every field:

```
awk -F '\t' '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print $i > "file" i}' < file
```

Or to avoid reading the file twice, with pipes and 2 `cut` invocations, with a shell like AT&T ksh, zsh or bash with support for process substitution:

```
< file tee >(cut -f2 > file2) | cut -f1 > file1
```

Beware that `ksh` and `bash` don't *wait* for that `cut` command running in the process substitution, so in those shells, `file2` may not be complete by the time you run the next command after that.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do like this:

```
cut -f1 input | tee output1 | cut -f1 > output2
```

If your desire filed is first and second columns.